# How to access link fields (url and text) value separately in views template?

Tags: views, 8, theming

My views block has a *Link* field named `field_link`, attached to a *Content Type* named `products`, and I'm trying access link field values(url and text) separately in views template `views-view-unformatted.html.twig`.

Following code gives the formatted html.

```
{{ row.content['#view'].style_plugin.render_tokens[ loop.index0 ]['{{ field_link }}'] }}
```

formatted html:

```
<a href="example.com/product-list" tabindex="-1">View Products</a>
```

But I want to access the link fields(url and text) value separately. Any help will be appreciated.

I am not able to check `row` variable via kint/dump as I am getting `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Easy way in Views UI add field_link 2 times.

in 1) Exclude from display, Select url only, and Show url as plain text.
which will give you the url only.

[image]

in 2) Exclude from display, and REWRITE RESULTS -> Strip HTML tags
which will give you the  title only.

[image]

Then in a custom field you can use twig  URL: {{ field_link }} Url Title: {{ field_link_1 }}

then in your custom template you can use them ...

Option 2) almost as easy create a custom field formatter based on 
Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\LinkSeparateFormatter.php